# How can i run IIS7 faster?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have some websites and i'm using different methods like jQuery src overwriting etc.
My pages have lots of text and pictures. I turned on server side compression for iis7.

My server (private server) is has hi configuration: IBM 8GB Ram 300GB Raid10 Intel E5540

My Bandwith: 10Mbit - 100Mbit

But i need more speed on server side when page publishng and serving...

Can anybody help me? What are ways have more speed?

Comment: "But i need more speed on server side when page publishng and serving...

" - does not constitute a question...

Answer (score 0):

Increase the bandwidth. I got 20 Mbit at home. 10 concurrent visitors with that bandwidth will cut performance of your server in half.